# deep copy cloning via serialization

Tags: c#

I came accross this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/SerializedObjectCloner.aspx

and would like to use it to deep copy a object graph. Is it sufficient to mark all the classes that potentially participate in the object graph with:

```
[Serializable()]
```

and then invoke the clone method as suggested in the article?

I have my doubts that it is that simple and I may have to implement more?! Thought I ask the experts first before I dig any deeper.

Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `SerializableAttribute` on a class means that all the fields of the object (except those you attribute with `NonSerialized`) will be serialized (and so they, themselves, need to be serializable). For simple cases that is enough, but for more complicated objects, you might want to look at implementing `ISerializable`, which will transparently work with the code in the article. It very much depends on your exact situation. For simple cases, `SerializableAttribute` by itself is enough.

Comment: A simple case is one using all primitive objects (strings, ints etc), a more complex case is an object holding a list of other custom objects that may or may not be serializable in themselves.

Comment: But if I mark all my custom objects classes with [Serializable()] I should be ok shouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, but there's things like loops in the graph, or fields you don't want to serialize pointing outside the graph, then it can get complicated...

Comment: PS you don't need the `()` on the attribute declaration, `[Serializable]` will work just as well